# Android lockCanvas() returns canvas on one device but on another returns null

Tags: java, android

I have got the following code:

```
public void messageReceived(String message) {
    ...
    ...
    synchronized (getHolder()) {
        if(isCreated) {
             Canvas canvas = getHolder().lockCanvas();
             if (canvas != null) {
                   draw(canvas);
                   getHolder().unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas);
             }
        }
    }
    ...
    ...
}
```

The problem is this: on my HTC Desire(Android 4.1.2) the method `getHolder().lockCanvas()` returns canvas which I then use to draw things on it. BUT on my friends smartphone(Android 4.2.2) it returns null so I can't draw on it. Any Ideas?

**EDIT**
I've changed the code a little bit just to be sure:

```
synchronized (getHolder()) {
    if(isCreated && !isLocked) {
        Canvas canvas = getHolder().lockCanvas();
        isLocked = true;
        if (canvas != null) {
                draw(canvas);
                getHolder().unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas);
                isLocked = false;
        }
    }
}
```

isCreated and isLocked are public static booleans.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, I made the canvas public static property and it Works!!

```
if(isCreated) {
    synchronized (getHolder()) {
        if(canvas == null)
             canvas = getHolder().lockCanvas();
             if (canvas != null) {
                 draw(canvas);
                 getHolder().unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas);
                 canvas = null;
             }
        }
}
```